# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.deploy.kubernetes.submit.Client

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I am running a sample spark job in kubernetes cluster with following command:

```
bin/spark-submit \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master k8s://https://XXXXX \
  --kubernetes-namespace sidartha-spark-cluster \
  --conf spark.executor.instances=2 \
  --conf spark.app.name=spark-pi \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.docker.image=kubespark/spark-driver:v2.1.0-kubernetes-0.1.0-rc1 \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.docker.image=kubespark/spark-executor:v2.1.0-kubernetes-0.1.0-rc1 \
  examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.1.0-k8s-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 1000
```

I am building the spark from [apache-spark-on-k8s](https://github.com/apache-spark-on-k8s/spark.git)

I am not able find the jar for `org.apache.spark.deploy.kubernetes.submit.Client` Class.

Comment: I too see the same issue. Please see my command bin/spark-submit --master k8s://https://openshift.<>:8443 --kubernetes-namespace argos --deploy-mode cluster --name spark-agg --class spark_structured_aggregator.main.Aggregator --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.docker.image=kubespark/spark-driver:v2.2.0-kubernetes-0.5.0 --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.docker.image=kubespark/spark-executor:v2.2.0-kubernetes-0.5.0 --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark local:///home/binaries/agg-0.0.52-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved. We need to build the spark/resource-manager/kubernetes from the source.

Comment: Can you please explain what was done to resolve this issue? I've built spark/resource-manager/kubernetes from source successfully (build/mvn install -Pkubernetes -pl resource-managers/kubernetes/core -am -DskipTests
and build/mvn compile -T 4C -Pkubernetes -pl resource-managers/kubernetes/core -am -DskipTests). I still find this error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.Client"